# HTA documentGetElementById

Tags: javascript, html, windows, hta

I've created the following HTA file to be run from the Windows Desktop. However, it produces an error when trying to retrieve an HTML element by its ID. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="MSThemeCompatible" content="Yes"/>
        <TITLE>
            Protos Changer
        </TITLE>
        <HTA:APPLICATION
            ID = "oApp"
            APPLICATIONNAME = "Protos Changer"
            BORDER = "thick"
            CAPTION = "yes"
            ICON = "hw.ico"
            SHOWINTASKBAR = "yes"
            SINGLEINSTANCE = "no"
            WINDOWSTATE = "normal"
            SCROLL = "no"
            SCROLLFLAT = "yes"
            VERSION = "1.1"
            INNERBORDER = "no"
            SELECTION = "no"
            SYSMENU = "yes"
            MAXIMIZEBUTTON = "yes"
            MINIMIZEBUTTON = "yes"
            NAVIGABLE = "no"
            CONTEXTMENU = "no"
            BORDERSTYLE = "thin"
        />
        <script>
            function init()
            {
                page_table = document.getElementById('page_table')
            }
        </script>
        <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
        <!--
            body        {background:buttonface;color:buttontext;font:10pt Arial;overflow:hidden;}
            select      {}
        -->
        </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onload="init()">
        <table id="page_table"></table>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE promotes the `ID="page_table"` element to a global variable named `page_table` and it dislikes you reusing this.

Add `var` to override this; `var page_table = document.getElementById('page_table');`

Or just use `page_table` right off the bat.

Comment: I was wondering why it worked in a browser but not in an HTA. I guess this answers it.